# How to set IE to "No proxy" while launching webdriver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Folks,

Can anyone suggest me how to set IE to "No Proxy" while launching webdriver?

Comment: How do you instantiate the driver?

Comment: By default, it'll take the system proxy settings set in the Internet Options -> what are they set to?

Comment: @Arran : My system proxy setting in the Internet options is "Use a proxy server from a LAN"